# Cannot find Method inside Stream.generate().forEach()

Tags: java, java-stream

```java
System.out.println(GraphController.GRAPHPOOL.peek().getEdge());
    Stream.generate(() -> {
     try {
       return GraphController.GRAPHPOOL.take();
     } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
       return "Interrupted!";
     }
    })
    .forEach(g   -> {System.out.println(g.getEdge());}
    });
```

I am able to print the object `Edge` returned by `getEdge` out of `Stream.generate().forEach()`, however, within `forEach` I can access only object `g`.

When trying to access `g.getEdge()` I get an error as follows:

> `error: cannot find symbol`
>
> `System.out.println(g.getEdge());`
>
> `symbol:   method getEdge()`
>
> `location: variable g of type Object`

How can I access `g.getEdge()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

due to the call `GraphController.GRAPHPOOL.take();` returning a *different* type to the statement `return "Interrupted!"`, the elements returned by the generate intermediate method will all be of type `Object` and there is no such method called `getEdge()` within the `Object` class. To overcome the problem you can do something like:

```
.forEach(g -> {
       if(g instanceof TheType){
           System.out.println(((TheType)g).getEdge());
       }
       else{
           // "interrupted"
       }
   });
```

Also, note that the method [`generate(Supplier<T> s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) *returns an infinite sequential stream*, usually in cases like this you'll want to utilize [limit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) to truncate the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your `g` to the wished datatype. As you can read, the variable `g` is currently an `Object`. Simply cast it with `(neededObjectforGetEdge(g)).getEdge()`